# How to use method.inserAt(); correctly

Tags: java, bytecode

I try some Bytecode manipulation in my WebApplication and so far, so good.
Now I need to inject some byte code on some specific places in my code. I tried this with a `switch` statement and `method.inserAt();`,
but it won't show the results I want.

Here's my code for the manipulation

```
private void changeMethod(CtMethod method) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {

    if (method.hasAnnotation(Loggable.class)) {
        int linenumber = 0;
        int i = 0;
        switch(i) {
            case 0:  linenumber = 50;
                break;
            case 1: linenumber = 71;
                break;
            case 2: linenumber =  91;
                break;
        }

        method.insertAt(linenumber, "\n" +
                "        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {\n" +
                "            @Override\n" +
                "            public void run() {\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "                threadLogger.info(\"Testlog\");\n" +
                "\n" +
                "                try {\n" +
                "                    threadLogger.logCall(Webservice.this.getClass().getMethod(\"startThread1\"), \"Thread1\");\n" +
                "                } catch (Exception e) {\n" +
                "                    e.printStackTrace();\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        });\n" +
                "        thread1.start();");
        i++;

    }
}
```

Comment: "It won't show the results I want". And what results do you want?

Comment: That it shows the results I would get with the code so it calls the threadLogger.logCall() function what I've defined in another class and than it logs something to a file and a database.
That works I tried it without Bytecodemanipulation before :D

Comment: Are you sure you have the Loggable annotation set?

Comment: If I just use method.insetAfter or something like that all works fine

Answer (score 1):

Realise that here:

```
int i = 0;
switch(i) { ...
```

`i` is always going to be zero. Maybe you want to do something with that value?

Comment: Ok that migth be a lil problem ! :D but can try it on monday :s

Comment: so I changed my coe every time method gets called i will increase by one but that won't work.